# Associations in sequelize( v 4.3.0) with custom primary key

Tags: postgresql, associations, sequelize.js

I have two models below here:

Merchant:

```
'use strict';
var models = require('../models');
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
const Merchant = sequelize.define('Merchant', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
    }
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            Merchant.hasMany(models.Item);
        }
    }
});
return Merchant;
};


Item: 
'use strict';
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
var Item = sequelize.define('Item', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
    },
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    price: DataTypes.STRING,
    details: DataTypes.STRING,
    availability: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    itemImageUrl: DataTypes.STRING
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            Item.belongsTo(models.Merchant);
        }
    }
});
return Item;
};
```

Each merchant has many items. This two model does not generate any relationship in the database what i mean, item table should have a column called merchantId. Can anybody please look where is the issue i am generating. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solutions from their example. Here is the two sample code from their example, it might help others in future.

https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/user.js
https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/task.js

Full sample: 
https://github.com/sequelize/express-example